NX console in VS Code gives an error when starting the task
When executing task in NX Console in VS Code (React) sometimes I get the following:
Error running command nxConsole.run-task-projects-view: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'item'). This is likely caused by the extension that contributes nxConsole.run-task-projects-view.
I need to restart the VS Code to be able to start the task again.
Does anyone know how it can be resolved?

Is there something common amongst the occurrences of when the error is produced?
